# Which EXIF tag to set for the 35mm equivalent focal length?

Tags: lens, metadata, focal-length

For a manual lens ([*Rokinon 8mm f/3.5 Fisheye](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/769428-REG/Rokinon_FE8M_C_8mm_Ultra_Wide_Angle.html)) I want to add the focal length information to the EXIF metadata in the resulting pictures with [`exiftool`](https://ExifTool.org/). I use the lens on a Canon 60D body.

Obviously I need to write the tag

```
FocalLength
```

For the Rokinon I set it to 8mm. Additionally based on my camera with an APS-C sensor I want to set the 35mm equivalent focal length as well. ***What is the right tag for this?*** One candidate I discovered is

```
FocalLengthIn35mmFormat
```

However for another lens, the electronically connected *Canon EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM* this tag is not set!!! The derived (composite) tag `FocalLength35efl` is calculated, so the information must come from somewhere. According to details on the [exiftool website](https://ExifTool.org/TagNames/Composite.html) it might come from

```
 FocalPlaneXSize / FocalPlanYSize
```

For a manual lens, which tag should I write to reveal the 35mm equivalent info? So should I rather write `FocalPlaneXSize` than `FocalLengthIn35mmFormat`?

Comment: If you set the _real_ focal length, does Exiftool not compute the composite tag from there? (Does it set the focal plane size tags?)

Comment: @mattdm, FocalPlane???? are calculated and write in camera

Comment: @RomeoNinov Right, so, hence the question — if those are being written, isn't setting just `FocalLength` sufficient (and then FocalLengthIn35mmFormat will be calculated). I haven't experimented, but the question strongly implies that it isn't being written.

Comment: @mattdm, the software use "Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent" to calculate from FocalLength to FocalLengthIn35mmFormat

Comment: @RomeoNinov `ScaleFactor35efl` itself is calculated from the `FocalPlaneXResolution` et al tags.

Comment: @halloleo, yes, Scale factor is calculated and I demonstrate in my answer how

Answer (score 3):

Good practice is adding

```
0x920a Focal length
0x9205 Max Aperture Value
0xa405 Focal Length In 35mm Format (60D sensor active area has 26.82mm diagonal)
0xa432 Lens Info
0xa433 Lens Make
0xa434 Lens Model
```

Comment: ExifTool docs seem to indicate that the "Focal Length In 35mm Format" tag is computed on the fly, not something written. Can you go into a bit more detail here?

Comment: It should be computed if the tag is not present. The tag is listed in JEITA CP-3451.

Comment: If it's computed, is it still best practice to set it? What is it computed from? Why not just set those things directly?

Comment: If one uses the exact diagonal, it is worthwhile to include the correct value, and to follow the standard IMHO is also a good thing.

Comment: The *comments* to this answer shed light on my question! I will look in regards to FocalPlaneDiagonal et al at the EXIF data of pictures taken with the electronic lens and report back here.

Comment: @halloleo, please check my answer, I add the formulas for calculate all needed tags

Comment: @halloleo, There is much of a zoo in exif and makernotes. In a lot of cases software makes a guess based on some info which is not fully understood (as it is not documented in any open source docs coming from camera manufacturer). Your situation is different, you have a manual lens and you can enter the exact information manually ;)

Comment: @IliahBorg Thanksfor your info. When you say it is "good practice" to add these tags - Where do you base this statement on? Do you have any links?

Comment: @halloleo, If you look me up you will see I participate in raw processor development since 2003. So I deal with exif/makernotes mess daily, and saying "good practice" I only mean these tags make data unambiguous for raw processors. Exif tags have precedence over makernotes tags and composite (derived, calculated) tags 90% of time.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about the situation, I suggest not to write `FocalLengthIn35mmFormat` at all.

As mentioned in the question, metadata of pictures taken with an electronically connected lens (the *Canon EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM*) do not provide the `FocalLengthIn35mmFormat` tag.

`exiftool` calculates the composite tag `FocalLength35efl` from other information (as mentioned in @RomeoNinov's answer) and tests on pictures of the *manual* lens revealed that it does so even if you only set `FocalLength`  (as @mattdm had pointed out in a comment). The reason is that the Canon 60D body can and does set the EXIF tags `FocalPlaneXResolution`, `FocalPlaneXResolution`, FocalPlaneResolutionUnit for all lenses - electronic or manual.

So, in order to stay consistent with the EXIF metadata of electronically connected lenses on the Canon 60D body, do not write the `FocalLengthIn35mmFormat` tag.

Comment: @mattdm I know you pointed this out in a comment, but I think *this* answers the question, so I put it in an answer.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Thanks for the calculation and your comments, they helped me to get a better understanding!

Comment: If all you need is exiftool, you don't need this tag. EXIF standards, however, suggest otherwise. If you will be using some processing software, no guarantee it will calculate 35mm eq. same way as exiftool, or will calculate it at all. IMHO adding this tag is safe route.

Comment: @halloleo, FocalPlane?Resolution tags are characteristic of the camera, not of the lens and this is the reason they are in RAW file all the time :)

Answer (score -2):

The tag you search is named "Focal Length"

Here is what I see with 70D, Sigma 24-105/F4

> Focal Length                    : 80.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 126.1 mm)

FocalPlane???? tags depend on digital zoom

P.S. FocalLengthIn35mmFormat is calculated from FocalLength multiplied by "Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent"

P.P.S. Here are the formulas to calculate scale factor (because this is calculated value)

```
FocalPlaneXSize = SensorWidth / (FocalPlaneXResolution / 25.4) (if size is in inch, otherwise use 10)
FocalPlaneYSize = SensorHeight / (FocalPlaneYResolution / 25.4) (if size is in inch, otherwise use 10)
FocalPlaneDiagonal = sqrt(FocalPlaneXSize^2 + FocalPlaneYSize^2)
Crop Factor (ScaleFactorTo35mmEquivalent) = Full Frame diagonal / FocalPlaneDiagonal
```

(if someone need them)

Comment: This is just a restatement of things already said in the question.

Comment: I write above which tag should be used and get negative vote. Then explain how other tags are calculated (so not need to be in EXIF info). I really can't understand what OP expect as answer

Comment: The question says that halloleo is _already_ setting that tag, and that, as you repeat, `FocalLengthIn35mmFormat` is a derived tag. Presumably, that is not sufficient in practice, or else the question wouldn't need to have been asked. That's why I asked for clarification.

Comment: Hope this time with exact formulas will be happy. And will clarify his question :)

Comment: I still am not sure it addresses the actual problem. I guess we'll need to see what the original poster thinks!

Comment: Right. In reality we need exact measurements of the image-forming sensor area. Canon are using 5 different APS-C sizes, and the second best way to calculate dimensions is to start from pixel pitch and number of pixels in each direction (which, in turn, depend somewhat on the raw converter in use).

Comment: @IliahBorg, all above source parameters are available from standard CR2 file. So this is all you need to calculate the parameters OP search for.

Comment: @Romeo Ninov, Right again, but it depends on how the raw converter crops, and how accurate one wants to be. Canon data is valid for in-camera converter and DPP. Other converters may use more area, or less area.

Comment: @IliahBorg, we talk about tagging the file, not converting. So this is full RAW file with all the needed information to be tagged correctly!

Comment: @Romeo Ninov, Good conversion depends on on tag consistency. I hate to repeat it, but there is a standard for EXIF tags, and it includes the tag in question.

Comment: @IliahBorg, yes, I mention it above. And Canon are very consistent (IMHO) providing in RAW files the tags :)